# Oracle APEX Select RDS Tab in URL

Tags: oracle-apex

I am developing an application in Oracle APEX 5.1. I have a page which uses a region display selector. The default tab has general information which should be the active tab for anyone navigating to the page from within the app. The other tabs are detailed reports which are relevant to specific users. I want to provide these users with a URL to access the tab containing the reports that they're interested in.

I created a page variable, P14_ACTIVE_TAB, which is the static ID of the region associated with a particular tab. I use this variable in the following JavaScript code..

```
 selectTab = "$('#myRDS .a-Tabs').aTabs('getTabs')['#" + $v('P14_ACTIVE_TAB') + "'].makeActive();";     

 console.log(selectTab);

 eval(selectTab);
```

I have tested the code and it works correctly if I use it on a button, select list, etc. however I have been unable to get it to properly execute when a user navigates to the page using a URL like

```
 f?p=100:14:::::P14_ACTIVE_TAB:myReport
```

If I define a dynamic action on page load it appears that the page is being rendered after the code is executed so I still get the default tab. If I look at the console output I see the correct code, which I can then cut/paste as a console command to get the desired result. So it appears that I have the right code being executed at the wrong time.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can define the dynamic action to execute after the page has been rendered so the correct tab will be made active?

Thanks.

Comment: I recently experienced the same problem, albeit with slightly different JS. 
It seemed to execute, only to have something else reset the selection, regardless of RDS attribute selections.
I never found a solution, but we went with different UX anyway.

Comment: Maybe use a timer to run the code after a second or so?  Not ideal!